# How can I iterate over nested and optional record arrays in Ballerina?

Tags: foreach, record, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

In my Ballerina program I have the below nested record structure and, I want to iterate through the `profiles` array within `associatedProfiles` of an `Allotment` record.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```php
type Allotment record {
    string inventoryBlockName?;
    AssociatedProfiles associatedProfiles?;
};

type AssociatedProfiles record {
    Profile[] profiles?;
};

type Profile record {
    string creatorCode?;
};
```

I tried using a `foreach` loop as shown below, but the compiler is raising issues.

```php
foreach Profile profile in allotment.associatedProfiles?.profiles? {
    // Code logic here
}
```

So what is the recommended approach to iterate over optional nested records in Ballerina?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, it is recommended to assign the `allotment.associatedProfiles?.profiles` to a variable and perform an `is` check to eliminate the possibility of having `nil` values. This helps narrow-down the variable type to `Profile[]`.

```php
Profile[]? profiles = allotment?.associatedProfiles?.profiles;

if profiles is () {
    // Handle `profiles` being `()` due to `AssociatedProfiles` or `Profile` being `()`
} else {
    // `profiles` is `Profile[]`
    foreach Profile profile in profiles {
        io:println(profile.creatorCode);
    }
}
```

And if you choose to return or continue within the `if` block, the `else` block is not required, as the type will be narrowed after the `if` block anyway.

```php
Profile[]? profiles = allotment?.associatedProfiles?.profiles;

if profiles is () {
    // Handle `profiles` being `()` and return.
    return;
}

// `profiles` is `Profile[]` here.
foreach Profile profile in profiles {
    io:println(profile.creatorCode);
}
```